# Getting values from external API using Spring Boot - Rest Template

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have an external API (like this - "https://www.example.com/en/products.json") and once hit the url it gives a json response like this:

```
{
    "product1": {
        "title": "Digital Adopter",
        "description": "product description",
        "image": ""
    },
    "product2": {
        "title": "Router",
        "description": "product2 description",
        "image": ""
    }
}
```

I want to use RestTemplate to consume above url(https://www.example.com/en/products.json) and tried following code. But didn't get any response or any error. I have less experience in development using Spring Boot RestTemplate and Can someone help me to fix this?

JsontestApplication .java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JsontestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JsontestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
       public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
          return new RestTemplate();
       }
}
```

Controller Class - Controller1.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller1 {
    
       @Autowired
       RestTemplate restTemplate;

       @RequestMapping(value = "/jkl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String getProductList() {
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
          HttpEntity <String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
          
          return restTemplate.exchange("https://www.example.com/en/products.json", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
       }
    
}
```

In the application.properties file, I have set the port as server.port=8765 and application is running without any error. This is the url I hit using the Postman - http://localhost:8765/jkl

Comment: what response you are seeing in postman ?

Comment: @Deadpool I'm not getting any response or error. It is showing like this "Loading..."

Comment: Think this should work... Do you get a response from 'https://www.example.com/en/products.json'? Do you enter your endpoint (debug, system.out.println) ?

Comment: @DirkDeyne Yes, I'm getting a json response like I mentioned earlier. I just tried to consume that API using RestTemplate

Comment: Do you enter your endpoint getProductList() in your Controller1? (use debug or system.out.println to check)

Comment: @DirkDeyne No. I debugged the code and used system.out.println to check. Values are empty

Comment: then your Controller is probably not pick up by spring-boot: Reference: [structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code). 
Tip: The best way to start a spring-boot-project is via [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I'm not sure. [https://www.example.com/en/products.json] is an external json file. Using RestTemplate I think it is not possible to consume. But still trying different ways. I'm trying to download json file to resource folder and read it

Comment: Any solutions for this question are highly appreciated.